# Checking to see if String variable was modified or not, if not no Toast. But Toast is appearing always

Tags: java, android, string, firebase

Having a slight problem with some logic that I am trying to implement to test whether a `String` variable has been modified or not. So in `EditProfileActivity` the user has the option of changing their `name,username, and bio`. Only thing is that when they enter the `EditProfileActivity`, if the username was Not changed, then when the user clicks on the checkmark to save changes it checks to see if the username already exists in the database. If so, a `Toast message` comes up indicating that that username already exist, and for you to pick another one.

The problem is that if the user doesn't change anything, and clicks the checkmark the `Toast message` pops up anyways, because that username that the user didn't change exists in the database obviously.

How can I change the code or implement logic so that even if the user clicks in the checkmark, and if the username wasn't changed the `Toast message` doesn't pop up and just the Activity `finish();`?

I tried implementing another condition in the `updateProfile();` method to the `if statement` to check whether the original username was the same as the final username, but didn't work... I'm pretty sure that's where the I have to add another condition to check whether or not it's the same username. This is the logic that I added, but didn't work:

`&& !mUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals(mUsername1.toLowerCase())`.

[image]

**EditProfileActivity**

```
public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mClose, mCheckmark, mImageProfile;
    TextView mChangePhoto;
    MaterialEditText mName, mUsername, mBio;

    private String mUsername1;

    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    private Uri mImageUri;
    StorageReference mStorageReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        mClose = findViewById(R.id.close);
        mCheckmark = findViewById(R.id.post_checkmark);
        mImageProfile = findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        mChangePhoto = findViewById(R.id.text_view_change_profile_picture);
        mName = findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        mUsername = findViewById(R.id.username);
        mBio = findViewById(R.id.bio);

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user != null) {
                    mName.setText(user.getFullname());
                    mUsername.setText(user.getUsername().toLowerCase());
                    mBio.setText(user.getBio());
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(mImageProfile);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mClose.setOnClickListener(v -> new AlertDialog.Builder(EditProfileActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Exit without saving changes?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                    finish();
                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show());

        mChangePhoto.setOnClickListener(v -> CropImage.activity()
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
                .start(EditProfileActivity.this));

        mImageProfile.setOnClickListener(v -> CropImage.activity()
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
                .start(EditProfileActivity.this));

        mCheckmark.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            String str_name = mName.getText().toString();
            String str_username = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String str_bio = mBio.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str_username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_bio) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_name)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (str_username.length() > 20) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username cannot contain more than 20 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                updateProfile(mName.getText().toString(), mUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase(), mBio.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateProfile(String fullname, String username, String bio) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());

        mUsername1 = username.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        mUsername1 = username.replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");

        DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                boolean ifUserNameExists = false;
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    if (user != null) {
                        if (user.getUsername().equals(mUsername1.toLowerCase())) {
                            Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "That username has already been taken. Try another", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ifUserNameExists = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!ifUserNameExists) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("fullname", fullname);
                    hashMap.put("username", mUsername1.toLowerCase());
                    hashMap.put("bio", bio);

                    reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Username has been changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**UPDATED**

```
 mCheckmark.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        String str_name = mName.getText().toString();
        String str_username = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String str_bio = mBio.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str_username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_bio) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_name)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (str_username.length() > 20) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username cannot contain more than 20 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (!mUser.getUsername().equals(mUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase()) && !mUser.getFullname().equals(mName.getText().toString()) && !mUser.getBio().equals(mBio.getText().toString())) {
                updateProfile(mName.getText().toString(), mUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase(), mBio.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot of database structure along with the value which you are changing.

Comment: @Dharmaraj okay, just posted it. Goes like this ```Users > uniqueId > username, name, etc```. Value that I am checking if it was changed or not is Username

Comment: I feel this can be an issue if case of that field is not handled correctly. Can you add LOG statements and check those values if they are the same or not ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj thanks for the help buddy. The below answer worked fine!

Comment: Cool. Case of strings can be painful to deal with :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this solution work for you?

```
private User user;
```

When user is fetched from database save user:

```
user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

And before calling updateProfile() check if username is equal to user.username

```
if(!user.username.equals(mUsername.getText().toString())){
    updateProfile(mName.getText().toString(), 
    mUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase(), mBio.getText().toString());
}
```

Like this you will not make unnecessary calls to Firebase.

Comment: This didn't work man. It changes the username always, and doesn't check if the username already exists in the database for some other user.

Comment: Hmm, this is to prevent call to Firebase if user did not change username. I think you need to add  toLowerCase() to if statement. Like this if(!user.username.equals(mUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase())), if this does not work try to add logs and debug to see what is different.

Comment: Okay, this worked. No Toast message if username wasn't changed... Thanks!

Comment: Hey buddy, I'm actually having problems I just noticed with the other fields. EditProfile has Name, Username, and Bio and the code which you helped me implement now only listens for if there were changes to the username, but I also need it to listen for changes with name and bio. So I tried changing the code to the above UPDATED part, but hasn't worked. Still only listends for changes for the username. How can I solve this?

Comment: For example, if I change the just want to change the bio and not the username and then click on the checkmark it doesn't do anything. Same for name. It's only listening for the username and I implemented code to try to fix it, but didn't work...

Comment: You will need to change your logic a bit. When you are checking if username exist you fetch all users and then loop through them. That means that your current user will be in that list too and username will always exist. When you find user with same username check if their id is the same (you have id field in database screenshot). If current user and fetched user id matches then set ifUserNameExists = false.

Answer (score 0):

one logic that could work.

when user enter `EditProfileActivity` you may want to save user info that you retrieved  from db into local variables. when user clicks on the checkmark to save changes you just need to compare what user input with your local variables. if they don't match, this means user have changed their profile info.

Comment: Should I save them as String variable or something? Because the way that I have it now, the data recalled from the database fills the EditText spaces. Should I also add the variables into a String variable or something? Actually in the onClickListener for the checkmark I have ```String str_username = mUsername.getText().toString();```. Should I compare  the new username to this one?